# What heroes should Mercy damage boost versus shooting herself?

Tags: overwatch

In FuriousPaul's [guide for mercy](https://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/mercy.html), he recommends damage boosting Lucio if there is no other hero around, but Mercy's blaster plus Lucio's gun combined does more damage than 130% of Lucio's shots. So it should be a higher DPS for both of them to shoot and not worry about damage boosting. 
For which heroes is the total DPS higher when Mercy damage boosts them compared to when she shoots her blaster alongside them?

Answer (score 4):

It strongly depends on your own accuracy with the pistol. That pistol does miracles for me. It does some considerable damage and the headshots are quite impressive. It's also the same pistol as mechless D.Va.

This said, "boosting an inaccurate teamate vs shooting yourself and increasing your chance of actually touching the target" is the real question. Don't forget that it's "just" +30% damage versus your own full damage.

If your teamates are just spraying to zone, maybe you should do it to. Maybe you should stay hidden to prevent the enemy from spotting you if you have your ult.

Does the time to switch to your pistol matter in the current situation ? Is it a question of life or death (Genji chasing you) ?

There is no definite answer to this question in my opinion. Learn when to pull the pistol out and when not to. You'll be a better Mercy regardless of my opinion because you'll learn your own playstyle.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the +50% buff never reached live due to concerns about McCree being too strong when damage boosted. So Mercy's damage boost is +30%

Comment: You're right. My bad. Which increases even more my point. ^.^

Answer (score 2):

It's never a good idea to shoot as mercy if theres any character around, only use your sidearm if a hero flanks and your team can't protect you at this moment. Sometimes it's also advisable to keep shooting at a certain position if a hero keeps peeking quickly, for example hanzo shooting an arrow around the corner, since the projectiles of the caduceus pistol fly relatively slow, which makes timing a peek almost impossible.

The damage boost itself is also only advisable if everyone in the team is at full health, since you can't damage boost a dead hero.

Now if everyone is full hp and no one is flanking you, who should you boost?
Boosting is heavily dependent on the enemy's team heroes and on the heroes on your team. For example : Enemy team has a lot of low health characters that keep pushing forward too hard, it's smart to buff Reinhardt. If the enemy team has a lot of tanks, you should buff your snipers (Hanzo, Widowmaker) since they can bring down a tank really quick.

Also it's always a good idea to damage buff pharah, since she can hit multiple enemies at once.